# Tcl - How to replace ? with -

Tags: string, tcl, special-characters

(You'd think this would be easy, but I'm stumped.)

I'm converting an iOS note to a text file, and the note contains "0." and "?" whenever there is a list or bullet.

```
This was a bulleted list
? item 20
? Item 21
? Item 22
```

I'm having so much problem replacing the "?"

I don't want to replace a legitimate question mark at the end of a sentence, 
but I want to replace the "?" bullets with "-" (preferably anywhere in the line, not just at the beginning)

I tried these searches - no luck

```
set line "? item 20"
set index_bullet [string first "(\s|\r|\n)(\?)" $line]
set index_bullet [string first "(!\w)(\?)" $line]
set index_bullet [string first ^\? $line]
```

This works, but it would match any question mark

```
set index_bullet [string first \? $line]
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
How do I find and replace only question mark bullets with a "-"?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really wanting to replace a question mark where you've got a regular expression that describes the rule, the `regsub` command is the right way. (The `string first` command finds *literal* substrings only. The `string match` command uses globbing rules.) In this case, we'll use the `-all` option so that every instance is replaced:

```
set line "? item 20"
set replaced [regsub -all {(\s|^)\?(\s)} $line {\1-\2}]
puts "'$line' --> '$replaced'"
# Prints: '? item 20' --> '- item 20'
```

The main tricks to using regular expressions in Tcl are, as much as possible, to keep REs and their replacements in braces so that the you can use Tcl metacharacters (e.g., backslash or square brackets) without having to fiddle around a lot.

Also, `\s` by default will match a newline.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.  And it worked! :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that a character used to indicate a list item is the first character on the line or the first character after optional whitespace. To match a question mark at the beginning of a line:

```
string match {\?*} $line
```

or

```
string match \\?* $line
```

The braces or doubled backslash keeps the question mark from being treated as a `string match` metacharacter.

To find a question mark after optional whitespace:

```
string match {\?*} [string trimleft $line]
```

The command returns 1 if it finds a match, and 0 if it doesn't.

To do this with `string first`, use

```
if {[string first ? [string trimleft $line]] eq 0} ...
```

but in that case, keep in mind that the index returned from `string first` isn't the true location of the question mark. (Use
 `==` instead of `eq` if you have an older Tcl).

When you have determined that the line contains a question mark in the first non-whitespace position, a simple

```
set line [regsub {\?} $line -]
```

will perform a single substitution regardless of where it is.

Documentation:
[regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Peter!   There is one more question.  I don't really understand string match {\?*} Why do I need the asterisk?  Wouldn't that match the case where there is no "?"

Comment: Also, `$index_bullet` will have a value of `0` if the `?` is the first character in the line.

Comment: In the rules for string match patterns (which I should have mentioned, I'll try to fix that when I get to a computer -- basically they're similar to Unix glob patterns) * means the same as .* in regular expression patterns. With string match, you can't make partial matches, so * is necessary. As for string first, it returns the position within the string where the sought-for string starts, or -1 if it isn't present. It is not a boolean value.

Comment: No one said it was boolean.  The OP's original idea of using `string first` will work fine, simply check the returned value for 0 (i.e. the first position in the target string).

Comment: @BradLanam: I know. Since you mentioned it, I just thought it would be a good idea to clarify how it related to my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I did it in two steps:

1) First find the "?"

```
 set index_bullet [string first "\?" $line]
```

2) Then filter out "?" that is not a bullet

```
 set index_question_mark [string first "\w\?" $line]
```

I have a solution, but please post if you have a better way of doing this.
  Thanks!

Comment: If you intend those arguments to be regular expressions, 1) `string first` doesn't use regular expressions, and 2) because of the double quotes, they are passed as the strings "?" and "w?", anyway.